# Short scifi animation film with a boy-looking robot from a multi-level vertical world that was sent down to explore it

Tags: story-identification, horror, robots

Please help to find a short scifi animation film with a boy-looking robot  from multi-level vertical world that was sent down to explore it. He was put into some capsule that fell down, and while it was falling, some mummy-looking creatures shot it down, and only a head fell on some level even further. The boy's head was found by someone who made it a new body. Then the robot-boy met some creatures who broke walls with their giant hands, then there was some kind of worms one of those sucked the boy in etc.

I believe this was a low-budget one-man-made pilot film, probably made by some Asian guy. It is a fun watch, and I hope it made it to some realisation.

Comment: I think I saw this film...when I remember correctly, the style was clay motion like? And one of the last things you saw, was this 4 legged creature with a tail (could also be "male" genitalia oO ) I know, where to look for it and may be able to show you

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the short film "Junk Head" by Takahide Hori. A quick viewing of this video seems to include all the "scenes" you are describing.

It seems, the full film was realised. See the [official site](https://www.yamiken.com/junkhead).

Comment: That is a hell of a video for just one guy to produce